# need help on adding date column and int column

Tags: mysql, sql

`column1 = '2023-01-09'` and `column2 = '60'`

```
select (column1 + column2) as column3
```

i need column3 as their sum but the value appears is 20230169 instead of 2023-03-09

Answer (score 4):

You may use `INTERVAL` syntax here:

```sql
SELECT '2023-01-09' + INTERVAL 59 DAY;  -- 2023-03-09
```

But it seems that you really just want to add 2 months:

```sql
SELECT '2023-01-09' + INTERVAL 2 MONTH;  -- 2023-03-09
```